# How to prevent users from changing other users data in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, authorization

At the min, any user can book a holiday for ay employee,

I have added [Authorization] to the controllers, and @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)

in the layout so only logged in users can view the pages.  But how can I go about only allowing users to book a holiday for them selves

something like if loggedInUserID(is this assigned automatically when a user is created?) =currentPersoID, although this is only a guess and I would prob have to assign the same loggedInUserID to personID.

---

EDIT:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Holiday holiday)
{    
        var holidays = db.Holidays.Include("Person");
        HolidayList model = new HolidayList();

     //run through person 
     foreach (Person person in model.PList4DD)
        {
         //if Logged in user = person name
            if (HttpContext.User.Identity.Name == person.Name)
            {
                //allow
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.Holidays.AddObject(holiday);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }
            else
            { 
                return RedirectToAction("Index"); 
            }

        }

        model.PList4DD = db.People.ToList();
        model.HList4DD = db.Holidays.ToList();

        ViewBag.Id = new SelectList(db.People, "Id", "Name", holiday.Id);
        return View(holiday);
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: What on earth is going on here? Why do you even create `HolidayList model`? I cannot see anywhere where it is used, since PList4DD seems to be set AFTER it is used? Let me know if I am misunderstanding!

Answer (score 3):

In your controller, there is HttpContext.User.Identity.Name

It will give you the username of the currently logged in person. Maybe that might be a good place to start?

Comment: thanks for the reply, iv edited my original msg to include my code, it still allows any user to book for any employee, any suggestions? thanks

Answer (score 1):

So you need to add additional check against the username or userid:

I would assume that the model you are returning to the View is of type employee.

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Home(int id)
{
    Employee model = // Get employee by id
    return View(model);
}
```

Then inside your view you can check the username:

```
@model Employee
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && User.Identity.Name == model.UserName)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your view is only ever called from a restricted action, adding `[Authorize]` should be enough, there is no need to do `@if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)` in the view itself as the user should never reach it.

As for your actual problem, I would create view model for your booking view which contains the username (or id) of the current user, for simplicity take the Username e.g.

```
public class BookingViewModel
{
    [HiddenInput]
    public Guid Username { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Then in your view when you attempt to post back to the server you can validate whether the booking is valid e.g.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateBooking(BookingViewModel bookingModel)
{
    if (bookingModel.UserId == User.Identity.Name)
    {
        // proceed with booking
        return View("BookingComplete", bookingModel);
    }
    else
    {
        // add model state error
    }
    return View(bookingModel)
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, if you take a look at my original msg iv posted my code, but nothing is happening, any ideas? thanks

Comment: @John based on the update to your question, wouldn't you just eliminate the control which *allows* the user the ability to select different users? In my example, I store the username as a hidden field on the page which is then verified on the server side, that way the user can **only** create bookings for themselves. There is no notion of creating bookings for other users. If you do need a notion of this for managers etc. then you could pass a flag in with your view model which indicates the user *can* select a user, render the drop down and pass that value back in your post.